# 500 (Internal Server Error) AJAX, when data from select option FORM

Tags: javascript, ajax, forms, codeigniter

When I change input type="text" with select option. Console in browser say "500 (Internal Server Error)"

when input type text

```
<h5 class="breadcrumbs-title">Tambah Sub Barang</h5>
 <div class="row">
  <div class="input-field col s6">
   <input id="jenis" name="jenis" type="text" value="" class="validate">
   <label id="jenis" for="jenis">Jenis</label>
  </div>
   <div class="input-field col s6">
   <input id="ukuran" name="ukuran" type="text" value="" class="validate">
   <label id="ukuran" for="ukuran">Ukuran</label>
  </div>
  <div class="input-field col s7">
   <input id="merk" name="merk" type="text" value="" class="validate">
   <label id="merk" for="merk">Merk</label>
  </div>
  <div class="input-field col s5">
   <input id="jumlah" name="jumlah" type="number" value="" class="validate">
   <label for="jumlah">Jumlah</label>
  </div>
 </div>
```

when select option

```
<div class="row">
<select name="jenis" id="jenis" required="required">
    <option value="" disabled selected>Pilih Jenis Barang</option>
    <?php
    foreach ($jenis_barang as $x) {
        echo "<option value='$x->id_jenis'>$x->jenis</option>";
    }
    ?>
</select>
<select name="ukuran" id="ukuran" required="required">
    <option value="" disabled selected>Pilih Ukuran Barang</option>
    <?php
    foreach ($ukuran_barang as $x) {
        echo "<option value='$x->id_ukuran'>$x->ukuran</option>";
    }
    ?>
</select>
<select name="merk" id="merk" required="required">
    <option value="" disabled selected>Pilih Merk Barang</option>
    <?php
    foreach ($merk_barang as $x) {
        echo "<option value='$x->id_merk'>$x->merk</option>";
    }
    ?>
</select>
```

and this function with ajax, I have two array, barang_masuk and barang_master.

```
<script>
$("#form_barang").submit(function () {

    var kodebarang = document.getElementById("kd_barang").value.toUpperCase();
    var namabarang = $("#nama_barang").val();
    var kategori = $("#kategori").val();
    var satuan = $("#satuan").val();

    var barangmaster = {
        kd_barang: kodebarang,
        nama_barang: namabarang,
        kategori: kategori,
        satuan: satuan
    };

    barang_master.push(barangmaster);

    var base_url = "<?= base_url('barang/submit_barang'); ?>/";

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: base_url,
        data: {detail_barang: barang_masuk, barang_master: barang_master},
        dataType: "text",
        cache: false,
        success:
                function (data) {
                    window.location.href = "<?= base_url('barang') ?>";
                }
    });
    return false;
});
```

Comment: If you have an internal server error then you need to (a) Look at your server side code and (b) Look at the error message in the server logs

Comment: Edit your question and include the code for `submit_barang()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What is you `submit_barang` file doing. 500 is thrown because there is an error in the `barang/submit_barang` file.

Check the form submit without AJAX to see what errors it shows.

Or in the Developer tools, you can go to Network tab and click on the `barang/submit_barang` request to see the response of the request.

Once you have response, you can decide what's going wrong on `barang/submit_barang` script.

Comment: I'm having the same problem.  How did you resolve the error??

Comment: Please check the script where you are sending the AJAX request. Paste the code snippet here; I might be able to help more.